# centerX and Y contraints not correct with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am making a custom UICollectionViewCell, but when I want to center a view inside the default `contentView` with constraints (programmatically), it is displaying a random position.

Here's my code:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  merchantContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
  merchantContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 335),
  merchantContentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
  merchantContentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
])
```

And here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

The UICollectionViewCell's contentView is in black and the another view in blue.

What am I missing? I am using Xcode 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q), with the iOS 11 SDK.

Comment: Why not use the view debugger and find out? I think you'll find this quite, uh, revealing.

Comment: "Here's my code" but _here_ is that code? How are you handling the fact that cells are reused??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it myself.
My mistake that I set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false for the `contentView`, which is totally understandable now :)

So I just removed the following line:

```swift
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```